# How to mock iconfiguration.GetSection(MyNodeName).Get<MyClassObject>()

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, moq, appsettings

I have a node in appsettings.json file which looks like this

```json
"MyClassName": {
    "MyList1": ["x","y"],
    "MyList2": ["a","b","c"]
}
```

To save and use these lists I have a Class in my backend with 2 properties

```
public class MyClass
 {
    public List<string> MyList1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> MyList2 { get; set; }
 }
```

There is a method which populates these properties using `IConfiguration` like this

```
_iconfiguration.GetSection("MyClassName").Get<MyClass>();
```

I need to mock above line of code in my .NET Core application. For mocking I am using Moq(4.16.1)
I tried to mock it like this

```
_mockConfiguration
    .Setup(m => m.GetSection(It.IsAny<string>()).Get<Myclass>())
    .Returns(MyClassObject);
```

But I am obviously missing something since I am getting Unsupported expression error.
The error says something like this

> Extension methods (here: ConfigurationBinder.Get) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No need to mock `IConfiguration`. Use an actual instance with in-memory configuration to get the desired behavior

Comment: You  get the exception because the `Get` in this case is an extension method and MOQ does not mock extensions.

Answer (score 6):

You  get the exception because the `Get` in this case is an extension method and MOQ does not mock extensions

No need to mock `IConfiguration`. An actual instance can be built with in-memory configuration to get the desired behavior.

```
//Arrange
Dictionary<string, string> inMemorySettings =
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"MyClassName:MyList1:0", "x"},
        {"MyClassName:MyList1:1", "y"},
        {"MyClassName:MyList2:0", "a"},
        {"MyClassName:MyList2:1", "b"},
        {"MyClassName:MyList2:2", "c"},
    };

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings)
    .Build();

//...
```

The above will allow the `IConfiguration` instance to be used as needed.

Reference [Memory Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#memory-configuration-provider)

Comment: Even though there is the ability to use json files I would not recommend to use it in unit tests for the following reasons: 1) The config file and the related tests are disjoint, so it is harder to maintain them consistently. 2) It quite common to have a setup which works locally but fails on the CI pipeline's build agent. File access notoriously fragile.

Comment: @PeterCsala fair point. I'll remove that suggestion.

Comment: Wow.  This is an exercise with string magic!  But it works!  Upvote.  For future readers, the ":0" ":1" are the INDEXERS for the collection.  It took me about 20 minutes to figure out the magic string context for my collection-inside-a-collection custom configuration object.  But I got it.  Thanks!